# Difference between relative positioned pseudo element and absolute positioned pseudo element

Tags: css

Consider the following three scenarios:

Scenario One:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;    
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: darkred;
  position: relative;
}
```

Scenario Two:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;    
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: darkred;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Scenario Three:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;    
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: darkred;
  display:block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Scenario One (relative position) doesn't show the `darkred` pseudo element.  But when it's changed into `position:absolute` the pseudo element is visible. Also, as shown in scenario three, when I added a `display:block` property to scenario one (relative position), the element is visible.

Why does `relative` position requires `display:block` and `absolute` doesn't?

Comment: Jacefarm is correct. Additionally absolute position will position the pseudo content relative to the next highest 'position: relative/absolute;' element. More on position: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A pseudo class such as `:before` has a default `display` CSS property value of `inline`.

Elements that are `display: inline;` and `position: relative;` are not "block-level" elements by default, and if they have no content, they do not take up any width.  Thus, if you do not declare `display: block;` and you have an empty content declaration like `content: "";`, it will not take up any width at all in Scenario 1.

Elements that are `position: absolute;` are taken out of flow and are "block-level" elements with a default `display` CSS property value of `block`.  Because of this, Scenario 2 renders the `:before` pseudo element, honoring its width and height declarations.

Scenario 3 is successful because the `display` property has been explicitly set to `block`, which honors the width and height declarations.

You can see these default values being set by inspecting the `:before` element in your browser's web developer tools - see the tools' "elements" inspector.